# Skip non-development environment gems installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have some gems needed outside `development` environment. So I moved them to the corresponding group in `Gemfile` as follows:

```
group :staging, :production do
  gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter', '~> 5.2.0'
  gem 'ruby-oci8',                            '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.7'
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1.48', require: false
end
```

Nevertheless, after cloning the project, when running `bundle install` it still requires to install `ruby-oci8`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `bundle install` will install all gems in all groups in your `Gemfile`, except those declared for a different platform.

However, you can explicitly tell Bundler to skip installing certain groups with the `--without` option. This option takes a space-separated list of groups.

While the `--without` option will skip installing the gems in the specified groups, it will still download those gems and use them to resolve the dependencies of every gem in your `Gemfile`.

This is so that installing a different set of groups on another machine (such as a production server) will not change the gems and versions that you have already developed and tested against.

> *ref*: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-install.1.html

Comment: Yeah, thank you. My error was to think that by default Bundler will install only gems defined in `development` group.